# laravel 5 : how to create two types of 404 page depending on loggedin or not

Tags: laravel

I want to create two Layouts of 404 page depending upon whether user loggedin or out.
am using laravel 5.8.

I have tried  `@if (Auth::guest())` and `@guest` both inside `ExceptionHandler->render` and inside `errors\minimal.blade.php`
but none works.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-authuser-on-custom-404-page

Comment: Let's see your `ExceptionHandler.php` file.

Comment: `@auth` directive should work

Answer (score 1):

inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
         if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
         $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

           switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
               case 404:
                $guard=='guest'? return redirect('/login'):return view('frontend.error.404'); 
                break;
           }
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No , I am making a Admin Panel. so cannot distinguish by url. I want to do this -> If not logged in then instead showing a 404 page redirect him to Login page. otherwise a 404 page with proper header & menu

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my App\Http\Kernel.php. And now i can access Auth inside my Exception\Handler.php

protected $middleware = [

```
    **\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,**

];
```

Problem solved. Thanks Game07er for link

Comment: It should be noted that adding the session to the global middleware is not a valid solution for applications which have a stateless API.  Creating your own Exception handler as @SaurabhMistry posted is a much better option in the long run.